# php.ini open_basedir restrictions Linux

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to include some JS to my php; PhantomJS. PhantomJS is installed properly.

But trying to include the framework in php causes problems.

> Warning: is_executable() [function.is-executable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/bin/linux-x86/phantomjs) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/username/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/)

So I opened the php.ini file and added:

```
open_basedir = "/usr/local/bin/linux-x86/"
```

Restarted Apache and checked the phpinfo();

> open_basedir
>   Local Value: /home/shappznet/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/
>   Master Value: /usr/local/bin/linux-x86/

But why is it still refusing to include the file?

Comment: Which Linux do you use? Do you have SELinux installed ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux)?

Comment: My linux info: Linux srv1.concerningserver.com 2.6.32-042stab093.4 #1 SMP Mon Aug 11 18:47:39 MSK 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Problem solved... I was looking at the wrong server..... Gr...